# Is there a way in jQuery to select all elements with "data-*" attribute name

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way in jQuery to select all elements with "data-*" attribute name.

```
<div data-user="1">
    <span data-name="Richard"></span>
    <label></label>
</div>
```

Like on the sample HTML above I want to select **data-user** and **data-name** elements. The problem is "data-" attribute can be anything (like data-abc) that is why I want to select attributes with "**data-***". I have looked at all jQuery attribute selector and cant find anything that does what I need. I cant use contains since text inside an element might have data- prefix.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wildcards in jQuery selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376431/wildcards-in-jquery-selectors)

Comment: not a duplicate, that's a different question

Comment: good question, but i think the answer is no (despite all the bogus answers you seem to be getting from folks that don't understand the question)

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery attribute name contains](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543733/jquery-attribute-name-contains)

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I updated "attribute" to "attribute name" to further clarify the intent of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery doesn't really have such a method, other than the attributes selectors you've ruled out.
You'd have to filter or just make your own method, like so :

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], { 
    data: function(el) { 
        return !jQuery.isEmptyObject( $(el).data() );
    }    
});
```

that can be used like

```
$('*:data')
$('div:data')
$('.class:data')
```

etc. and returns only the elements that has data associated with it

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/GP3z8/3/)

Comment: @StephenThomas - So what is the OP asking ?

Comment: "I cant use contains since text inside an element might have data- prefix."

Comment: @StephenThomas - I thought the question was "Is there a way in jQuery to select all elements with "data-*" attribute.", what the OP can't do isn't very relevant ?

Comment: actually, i think you're right. i retract my comment

Comment: @StephenThomas - I think I'm right as well, but I'm not sure, that's why I asked ?

Comment: I should note that this doesn't *just* check for data attributes, I wrote this to check for elements with any data set, both data attributes and data set internally by jQuery using data()

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that jQuery does not have that feature. The sample code that you had works perfect. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some vanilla HTML5:

```
Array.prototype.filter.call(
   document.querySelectorAll("body *"), 
   function(node) { 
      return Object.keys(node.dataset).length > 0;
   }
)
```

And some jQuery:

```
$("body *").filter(
   function() { 
      return !$.isEmptyObject(this.dataset) 
    }
)
```

Comment: I actually though about using dataset, but then it only works in IE11+.

Comment: Yeah, I jumped on the HTML5 tag.

Answer (score 0):

See the JQuery API Documentation regarding the [Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/).  Thias should get you started.

Comment: no. that's not helpful. the link is about attribute values and the OP is asking about attribute names I don't down vote answers but someone else might, so you might want to delete your answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy solution to this problem. What I will do is

```
//Get all the elements in the document and filter those that have data-* attribute

$('*').filter(function() {
   var attrs = this.attributes; //get the attributes array-like object for each DOM element

   for (var i=0, len=attrs.length; i<len; i++) {
     var attr = attrs[i];
     if (attr.name.match(/^data-/)) {
       return true;
     }
  }
});
```

I tested this and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You could roll through all the DOM elements and find just the ones with data elements...

```
var i, max, all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for ( i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++ ) {
    // Do something with the element here
    var data = $( all[i] ).data();
    if( !$.isEmptyObject( data ) ){
        //if you find a non-empty object, the element has a data-* attribute, do something with it.
        console.log( data );
    }
}
```