# jQuery - How to select value by attribute name starts with

Tags: jquery, selector, attr, startswith

I want to select attribute value by giving attribute name (only starts with)
For instance if we have html tag

```
<div class = "slide"  data-confirmID = "46" confirmID = "54"/>
```

I want to select the value from the attribute starts with `data-`

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: What if you have multiple attributes that start with `data-`? Which value should you get?

Comment: jQuery has a starts with selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

Comment: In my scenario i have only one.. so if I could select attribute name starting with 'data-', that should do

Comment: @Moob That's for finding the elements with a `data-` attribute. He wants to find the _value_ of the attribute, not use it as a selector.

Comment: @Moob -  I actually wanted to select based on attribute name something like $('div').attr('data-*');

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want all data-* attributes, you can iterate through jq data object:

```
$('.slide').each(function(){
    for(data in $(this).data())
        console.log(data); // returns confirmID so element as an attribute `data-confirmID`
});
```

But this data object can contains other keys which aren't attribute, setted for example by some plugins.

## EDIT

To get all kinds of attribute to "starts with", you can customize your own jQuery selector:

```js
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    attrStartsWith: function (el, _, b) {
        for (var i = 0, atts = el.attributes, n = atts.length; i < n; i++) {
            if(atts[i].nodeName.toLowerCase().indexOf(b[3].toLowerCase()) === 0) {
                return true; 
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }
});

//e.g:
$('.slide:attrStartsWith("data-")').css('color', 'red');
$('.slide:attrStartsWith("conf")').css('color', 'blue');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide" data-confirmID="46" data-testID="666">1</div>
<div class="slide" confirmID="54" >2</div>
```

If on the opposite side, you want to check for attribute ends with specific string, you can use:

```js
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[':'], {
    attrEndsWith: function (el, _, b) {
        for (var i = 0, atts = el.attributes, n = atts.length; i < n; i++) {
          var att = atts[i].nodeName.toLowerCase(),
              str = b[3].toLowerCase();
            if(att.length >= str.length && att.substr(att.length - str.length) === str) {
                return true; 
            }
        }
        
        return false;
    }
});

$('.slide:attrEndsWith("testID")').css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide" data-confirmID="46" data-testID="666">1</div>
<div class="slide" confirmID="54" >2</div>
```

Comment: @A.Wolff Can't we access other attributes which not start from "data" ?

Comment: @NishanSenevirathna Sure, you need to firstly get all attributes and then apply your logic, e.g to get attributes see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048720/get-all-attributes-from-a-html-element-with-javascript-jquery

Comment: @NishanSenevirathna Updated answer with custom selector

Answer (score 3):

You could do it as a jQuery plugin. I'm not convinced its the right way to go about it but here's an example:

```js
(function($) {
    $.fn.attrBegins = function(s) {
        var matched = "";
        this.each(function(index) {
            $.each(this.attributes, function( index, attr ) {
                if(attr.name.indexOf(s)===0){
                   matched =  attr.value
                }
            });
        });
        return matched;
    };
})(jQuery);

//example use
var val = $('div').attrBegins('data-');
alert(val);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slide" data-confirmID="46" confirmID="54" />
```

Answer (score 2):

@Moob aproximation to jQuery *attrBegins* plugin, returns the attribute name (a string), when are matches... of a single element (ignoring multiple matches). 
I addapted the code to return a JQuery Collection with the matching elements.

Here is the code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.attrBegins = function(s) {
        var matched = [];
        this.each(function(index) {
            var elem = this;
            $.each(this.attributes, function( index, attr ) {
                if(attr.name.indexOf(s)===0){
                   matched.push(elem);
                }
            });
        });
        return $( matched );
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**USAGE EXAMPLE...**

HTML :

```
<div>
    <div data-pet-dog></div>
    <div data-pet-cat></div>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
 var foo = $("div").attrBegins("data-pet");
// results into... foo = [ <div data-pet-dog></div> , <div data-pet-cat></div> ]
```

NOTE: To prevent performance issues when **selecting elements wich have an attribute name that starts with a custom string** using *attrBegins*, is recomended to narrow as much as possible the original selector, to reduce the collection of elements to iterate. 
*attrBegins* just filters the preselected elements collection, it does not explore the child elements of provided set of items.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes are properties of the element, so you can use a `for-in` loop

```
for (var prop in element) {
    if (prop.indexOf('data-') == 0) {
        var val = element[prop];
        break;
    }
}
```