# jQuery select by custom attribute prefix with and without data-

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

The question to select a custom tag is asked many times.

`<div mytag="foo"></div>` would be `$('[mytag]')` or `$('div[mytag]')`.

Now my question is about the fact that the above isn't valid HTML5.
This however would be valid: `<div data-mytag="foo"></div>`.

Now my assumption was that -if I offer the user to use `mytag="foo"` *or* `data-mytag="foo"`- I could do this: `$('[$mytag]')`. Where $ = everything that is prefixed mytag.

Why is this wrong and how could I resolve this?

PS:
Currently I'm doing: `$('[mytag], [data-mytag]')` which looks *design-flawish*...

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery - How to select value by attribute name starts with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657398/jquery-how-to-select-value-by-attribute-name-starts-with)

Answer (score 0):

It's wrong because you can't match attribute names dynamically using an attribute selector, only attribute values. You say "$ = everything that is prefixed mytag", but there is no such syntax.

`[mytag], [data-mytag]` isn't exactly a design flaw by itself so much as it highlights a design flaw in the original markup. If it bothers you, you can ensure that any custom attribute the user attempts to enter is prefixed with "data-" automatically if the prefix isn't already supplied, so you never have to worry about user-defined attributes lacking the prefix.

Comment: O, thanks for this.
I wasn't aware of this.
You are basically saying that calling `data-mytag` will *always* return the value of `mytag`?
...let's give it a try... :-)

Comment: @bvl: No, I'm saying to never allow `mytag` in the first place. If the user tries to add an attribute called `mytag`, you reflect it as `data-mytag` in the markup.