# How can I find and select all elements which have data attribute start with specific word with using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute

I want to find and select all element which have data attribute start with "data-qu" under wrapper div. How can I do this with using jquery?

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div data-qu-lw="1"></div>
    <div data-qu-md="2"></div>
    <div data-res-kl="1"></div>
    <div data-qu-lg="3"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way select those, like this `$('.wrapper').find('^data-qu')` or similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var filteredElements = $('.wrapper > div').filter(function(){
  var attrs = this.attributes;
  for (var i=0; i<attrs.length; i++) {
      if (attrs[i].name.indexOf("data-qu")==0) return true;
  }         
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

ref: [jQuery attribute name contains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543733/jquery-attribute-name-contains)

you can do like this.

```
$('.wrapper div').filter(function() {
  for (var property in $(this).data()) {
    if (property.indexOf('data-qu') == 0) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
});​
```

Answer (score 2):

Try utilizing `.filter()` , `test()` , `Object.keys()`

```js
$(".wrapper *").filter(function() {
  return /^qu/.test(Object.keys($(this).data())[0])
}).css("color", "aqua")
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div data-qu-lw="1">1</div>
    <div data-qu-md="2">2</div>
    <div data-res-kl="1">1</div>
    <div data-qu-lg="3">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why so you can directly use the html of element itself to match

Comment: @Raghavendra _"why so you can directly use the html of element itself then "_ Not certain interpret comment correctly ?

Comment: @guest271314 $('.wrapper *') does universal selector cause low performance?If we think like CSS selectors

Comment: i mean you can match '<div data-qu-lw="1"></div>'.match(/qu.*?>/). why objects keys all things

Comment: @Raghavendra jQuery `.data()` stores `data-*` attribute as `Object` having key / value pairs ; where `key` is name , or `*` of `data-*` ; e.g.,`qu-lw`

Comment: anyway it helps the answer bye

Comment: @midstack _"$('.wrapper *') does universal selector cause low performance?"_ See at Question _"want to find and select **all element** which data attribute start with "data-qu" under wrapper div"_ Is requirement to select _all_ elements which have `data-*` beginning with `"qu"` , or only `div` elements ?