# Regex on Javascript attribute name

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, attributes

I would like to create a function to analyse attributes (like `data()` function does) to select attributes starting with a pattern. Here is an example:

```
<span data-foo-bar data-foo-foo>my example<span>
```

I would like to select `data-foo-bar` and `data-foo-foo` because it starts with the regex `data-foo-*`.

I found a lot of way to use regex on attribute value but not directly on the attribute name.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: regex : `\bdata-foo-\S*`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543733/jquery-attribute-name-contains

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Could you add an example please?

Comment: "data-foo-bar".match(/^data\-foo/) or without regex just "data-foo-bar".indexOf("data-foo") === 0

Comment: or even better http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657398/jquery-how-to-select-value-by-attribute-name-starts-with

Comment: @BenG, I think what I'm looking for it what you've suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex

```
var isDataFoo = function(name) {
  return name.match(/^data\-foo/) !== null
}
```

Or just string indexOf

```
var isDataFoo = function(name) {
  return name.indexOf('data-foo') === 0
}
```

Comment: I would like to use it directly with `jQuery`. I think @BenG, it's what I was searching.